# Google Maps embed API restrictions not working locally

Tags: google-maps, security

I have a Google Maps API key restricted by HTTP referrers. The restriction works when I try to load an embed map in an iframe, in a hosted website with a real domain.

However, when I try it locally, the restriction has no effect (load though file://local/path/to/test.htm), and the iframe loads it's content without any warning or error message.

My concern is if that key could be abused by attackers to consume credits and increase the billing associated with my account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is why:

If the embed maps are using the [basic embed requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/usage-and-billing#embed), Google will not check restrictions, as the usage of that API is free.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Seattle&key=KEY
```

But if the [advanced map modes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/usage-and-billing#embed-advanced) are used, then the restrictions apply.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=record+stores+in+Seattle&key=KEY
```